# Can i show a custom view from within a broadcast receiver in the background?

Tags: java, android

I have a broadcast receiver that works in the background of my app
and I want to show a custom popup view on the phone every time it triggers.
(every time the onReceive method is called)

can I show a custom view of my own (just some pic with some text in it) 
on top of the phone from within the BroadcastReciever?
(very similar to what the messenger is doing when u get a message in facebook)

do you have a code example of how I can achieve that?

here is my receiver

```
public class PhoneStateReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Ringing State Number is -"+incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getContactList(context, incomingNumber);
        }
        if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Received State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Idle State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If i got your question correctly, you need to create a custom activity and call it whenever you want.

Comment: Is this registered on activity level or on manifest level?

Comment: I just want to show a square with some image and a few textx on it, on top of the OS ,
very similar to what the messenger is doing when u get a message in facebook, that it pops up ontop of everything

Answer (score 1):

you can use widgets for this case
 https://www.raywenderlich.com/33-android-app-widgets-tutorial

Comment: yea but a widget will show me something in the background, i want something to popup, like in messenger

Comment: like this ??
https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064